# Multiple PreRender IO calls in HaProxy

Tags: web-services, haproxy

I am using the suggested haproxy configuration to redirect bot traffic to reprender, it works great but I now have another site hosted on the same server but need haproxy to redirect to a different prerender account if the difference site, I cannot figure out how to do this, does anyone have a clue?

```
`# prerender.io
acl user-agent-bot hdr_sub(User-Agent) -i baiduspider twitterbot facebookexternalhit rogerbot linkedinbot embedly showyoubot outbrain pinterest slackbot vkShare W3C_Validator
acl url-asset path_end js css xml less png jpg jpeg gif pdf doc txt ico rss zip mp3 rar exe wmv doc avi ppt mpg mpeg tif wav mov psd ai xls mp4 m4a swf dat dmg iso flv m4v torrent ttf woff
acl url-escaped-fragment url_sub _escaped_fragment_

use_backend prerender if user-agent-bot !url-asset
use_backend prerender if url-escaped-fragment !url-asset
`
```

Comment: The order of the use_backend directives matter. do you want the url-escaped-fragment to happen first or second?

Comment: @NickRamirez I'm a noob with haproxy tbh, I got the snippet from their website. but I want to filter it via website now, what would you recommend?